# Issue with getting data from api

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm trying to call two api's. The first one is successfully returning data. The second one is not. Please somebody help

```
$(function() {
      $.getJSON('https://freegeoip.net/json/').done(function(location) {
        $("div").html(JSON.stringify(location));

        $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + location.latitude + '&lon=' + location.longitude + '&units=imperial&appid=b3ce5b75f220eaf1db1df46a93a6595e',
          function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
      });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The second one is not"? Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: Your code is working as is on my browser.

Comment: Are you trying to load it on a https domain? And what error are you getting in your  console? Because you'r code looks fine.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in console. I'm doing it in codepen.io. codepen.io is https.

Comment: remove the https:// from the url and visit it again that should work. But this won't really fix your problem.

Comment: the https one is returning data. I'm having issue with the http one

Comment: You can check my answer. It will help you in understanding the issue. Thanks

Comment: @VishnuMR did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with **`http`** is that https://codepen.io was loaded over **`https`** protocol but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint.

> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=17.3753&lon=78.4744&units=imperial&appid=b3ce5b75f220eaf1db1df46a93a6595e

Hence, this request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS or directly inject your code in the application instead of running over online tools.

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
      $.getJSON('https://freegeoip.net/json/').done(function(location) {
        $("div").html(JSON.stringify(location));

        $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + location.latitude + '&lon=' + location.longitude + '&units=imperial&appid=b3ce5b75f220eaf1db1df46a93a6595e',
          function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```